# Add Click event to DataTable (powershell)

Tags: powershell, datatables

So I have a button that pulls this function to search for all the Install.Log files on a machine. 
After loading the results, I want to have a double click event on the a row, where it will open the log file.

I am having a hard time adding a click event, and anytime I try to find something related to Datatables I find stuff about java. Any guidance or links would be appreciated.

Thanks in advace

## TEST THE CODE FOR YOUR SELF BY RUNNING THIS IN PS ISE

```
$ComputerName = "your computer name here"
[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('presentationframework')
[xml]$XAML = @'
<Window Name="Form"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        Title="Install Logs" Height="488.773" Width="797.65" Icon = "\\bconac01\ds-support\GS_IT\Tools\Test Tools (Alx)\Tool\icon.ico" ShowInTaskbar="False"> 
    <Grid Margin="0,0,-8,-21">
        <DataGrid Name="DataGrid1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="368" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="772" Margin="10,41,0,0"/>
        <Label Content="Filter" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        <TextBox Name="FilterTextBox" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="26" Margin="78,10,0,0" TextWrapping="Wrap" Text="" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="172"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
'@

#Read XAML
$reader=(New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml) 
try{$Software=[Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )}
catch{Write-Host "Unable to load Windows.Markup.XamlReader. Some possible causes for this problem include: .NET Framework is missing PowerShell must be launched with PowerShell -sta, invalid XAML code was encountered."; exit}

# Store Form Objects In PowerShell
$xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | ForEach-Object{
    Set-Variable -Name ($_.Name) -Value $Software.FindName($_.Name)
    Write-host $_.Name
}

$Fields = @(
    'Name'
    'LastWriteTime'
)



#$Services = Get-WmiObject -Computer ($prebox.text + $device.text) -Class Win32reg_AddRemovePrograms | Select-object -Property *
$Services = Get-ChildItem \\$ComputerName\c$\build\logs -Include *install* -recurse -ErrorAction Stop | Sort-Object LastWriteTime -Descending


# Add Services to a datatable
$Datatable = New-Object System.Data.DataTable
[void]$Datatable.Columns.AddRange($Fields)
foreach ($Service in $Services)
{
    $Array = @()
    Foreach ($Field in $Fields)
    {
        $array += $Service.$Field
    }
    [void]$Datatable.Rows.Add($array)
}
#$filter = "DisplayName LIKE 'B%'"
#$Datatable.DefaultView.RowFilter = $filter



# Create a datagrid object and populate with datatable
$DataGrid1.ItemsSource = $Datatable.DefaultView
$DataGrid1.CanUserAddRows = $False
$DataGrid1.IsReadOnly = $True
$DataGrid1.GridLinesVisibility = "None"
$DataGrid1.Add_CellMouseClick({gridClick})

function gridClick(){
$rowIndex = $DataGrid1.CurrentRow.Index
$columnIndex = $DataGrid1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
Write-Host $rowIndex
Write-Host $columnIndex 
Write-Host $DataGrid1.Rows[$rowIndex].Cells[0].value
Write-Host $DataGrid1.Rows[$rowIndex].Cells[$columnIndex].value}

$FilterTextBox.Add_TextChanged({
    $InputText = $FilterTextBox.Text
    $filter = "Name LIKE '$InputText%'"
    $Datatable.DefaultView.RowFilter = $filter
    $DataGrid1.ItemsSource = $Datatable.DefaultView
    $form.Controls.Add($DataGrid1)
$Software.Controls.Add($DataGrid1)
})

# Shows the form
$statusBar1.Text = "Done."

$Software.Add_Shown({$Software.Activate()})
$Software.ShowDialog() | out-null
```

--Things Ive tried that are suggested.

[[image: what I see[2]]

[image: update]

Comment: can you share a sample log file?

Comment: I dont think I can as most of what is in them is pretty work sensitive stuff, but they are all in a specified folder and titled something like "SomeApplication_Install" or "SomeApplication_Uninstall" etc. I just need to be able to double click on it in the data table like I could in my file explorer, as they open up with our LogViewer program by default.

Answer (score 1):

Ok. Here's a sample with gridview cell click event. You can add cell double click event with `$DataGrid1.Add_CellMouseClick({gridClick})`

hope this should help

```
$form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(900,600)
$DataGrid1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView
$DataGrid1.Size=New-Object System.Drawing.Size(800,400)

$DataGrid1.Add_CellMouseClick({gridClick})

$form.Controls.Add($DataGrid1)


#Create an unbound DataGridView by declaring a column count.
$DataGrid1.ColumnCount = 4
$DataGrid1.ColumnHeadersVisible = $true

#Set the column header names.
$DataGrid1.Columns[0].Name = "Recipe"
$DataGrid1.Columns[1].Name = "Category"
$DataGrid1.Columns[2].Name = "Third COlumn"
$DataGrid1.Columns[3].Name = "Rating"

#Populate the rows.
$row1 = @("Meatloaf","Main Dish", "boringMeatloaf", "boringMeatloafRanking")
$row2 = @("Key Lime Pie","Dessert", "lime juice evaporated milk", "****")
$row3 = @("Orange-Salsa Pork Chops","Main Dish", "pork chops, salsa, orange juice", "****")
$row4 = @("Black Bean and Rice Salad","Salad", "black beans, brown rice", "****")
$row5 = @("Chocolate Cheesecake","Dessert", "cream cheese", "***")
$row6 = @("Black Bean Dip", "Appetizer","black beans, sour cream", "***")
$rows = @( $row1, $row2, $row3, $row4, $row5, $row6 )

foreach ($row in $rows){
    $DataGrid1.Rows.Add($row)
}


function gridClick(){
$rowIndex = $DataGrid1.CurrentRow.Index
$columnIndex = $DataGrid1.CurrentCell.ColumnIndex
Write-Host $rowIndex
Write-Host $columnIndex 
Write-Host $DataGrid1.Rows[$rowIndex].Cells[0].value
Write-Host $DataGrid1.Rows[$rowIndex].Cells[$columnIndex].value}


$form.ShowDialog()
```

Comment: I added the function to my script, but I am not seeing it add anything to my terminal.

added edit to OP.

Comment: post your updated code in question. try running the code in answer as it is using PowerShell to get an idea

Comment: I posted what I was running on your post.
But ill update my OP.

Comment: What powershell version you are using?

Comment: Version: 5.1.17763.771

Comment: did you add `$DataGrid1.Add_CellMouseClick({gridClick})` in your code to bind the event to function? Also did you run script in answer in PS ISE?

Comment: this is what I see with my script https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhL1T.png . Its writing cell values to console on double click.

Comment: I added a photo to OP of what I see.

Comment: error is not completely visible, can you put the error message in OP

Comment: I will try that, also that error was:
Method invocation failed because [System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid] does not contain a method named 'Add_CellMouseClick'.
At C:\Users\UserName\Desktop\Tools in Prog\RebootTool.ps1:553 char:1
+ $DataGrid1.Add_CellMouseClick({gridClick})
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Comment: added a new photo

Comment: try replacing Add_CellMouseClick with MouseDoubleClick like `$DataGrid1.MouseDoubleClick({gridClick})`

Comment: Causes a Unhandled Exception error. 
System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid does not contain a method name "MouseDoubleClick"

Comment: Check the OP. If you run that whole code it bring up my resaults. just make a folder in your C drive called Build/Logs/install.log

Comment: your sample works on its own, but I cant seem to get it to populate with the things I need it to pull (IE. File Names, Size, Destination)

Comment: Added another example with wpf + PowerShell

Answer (score 1):

As per your requirement here's one another sample I have created with WPF with PowerShell. You can bind the event using `$WPFListView.Add_MouseDoubleClick({gridClick})` and to access the selected cell value using column like `$WPFListView.SelectedValue.OriginalFileName`

Try this as it is in PowerShell ISE. [This is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cAioj.png)

```
##Sample DataTable 

$tabName = "SampleTable"

#Create Table object
$table = New-Object system.Data.DataTable “$tabName”

#Define Columns
$col1 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn OriginalFileName,([string])
$col2 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn FileDescription,([string])
$col3 = New-Object system.Data.DataColumn FileVersionRaw,([string])

#Add the Columns
$table.columns.add($col1)
$table.columns.add($col2)
$table.columns.add($col3)

#Create a row
$row = $table.NewRow()
$row.OriginalFileName = "Test Log"
$row.FileDescription = "Test log data"
$row.FileVersionRaw = "v1.0"

$row1 = $table.NewRow()
$row1.OriginalFileName = "IIS Log"
$row1.FileDescription = "IIS Sys log"
$row1.FileVersionRaw = "v2.0"

$row2 = $table.NewRow()
$row2.OriginalFileName = "User Data"
$row2.FileDescription = "User data details"
$row2.FileVersionRaw = "v1.0"

$row3 = $table.NewRow()
$row3.OriginalFileName = "Sys Info"
$row3.FileDescription = "System Info Details"
$row3.FileVersionRaw = "v2.0"

#Add the row to the table
$table.Rows.Add($row)
$table.Rows.Add($row1)
$table.Rows.Add($row2)
$table.Rows.Add($row3)

##Sample DataTable 

$inputXML = @"
<Window x:Class="FileVersionChecker.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:FileVersionChecker"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="FileVersionChecker" Height="350" Width="525">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="115*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="373*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="29*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ListView Name="ListView" Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="150" Margin="10,10,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="350">
            <ListView.View>
                <GridView>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="OriginalFileName" DisplayMemberBinding ="{Binding 'OriginalFileName'}" Width="100"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="FileDescription" DisplayMemberBinding ="{Binding 'FileDescription'}" Width="100"/>
                    <GridViewColumn Header="FileVersionRaw" DisplayMemberBinding ="{Binding 'FileVersionRaw'}" Width="100"/>
                </GridView>
            </ListView.View>
        </ListView>

    </Grid>
</Window>
"@       

$inputXML = $inputXML -replace 'mc:Ignorable="d"', '' -replace "x:N", 'N' -replace '^<Win.*', '<Window'

[void][System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName('presentationframework')
[xml]$XAML = $inputXML
#Read XAML

$reader = (New-Object System.Xml.XmlNodeReader $xaml)
try {
    $Form = [Windows.Markup.XamlReader]::Load( $reader )
}
catch {
    Write-Output "Unable to load Windows.Markup.XamlReader. Double-check syntax and ensure .net is installed."
}
 $xaml.SelectNodes("//*[@Name]") | ForEach-Object {Set-Variable -Name "WPF$($_.Name)" -Value $Form.FindName($_.Name)}


$WPFListView.ItemsSource  = $table.DefaultView
$WPFListView.Add_MouseDoubleClick({gridClick})

function gridClick()
{
  Write-Host ""  
  Write-Host "$($WPFListView.SelectedValue.OriginalFileName) ,  $($WPFListView.SelectedValue.FileDescription), $($WPFListView.SelectedValue.FileVersionRaw)"
}


$Form.ShowDialog() | out-null;
```